# Swift HTTP Request to Google Elevation API

Tags: swift, httprequest, google-elevation-api

Im trying to send requests to the Google Elevation API, I have successfully sent singular requests. Stated in the documentation for GE API is that a singular request can contain many coordinate evaluations if the coordinates are passed as a list separated by "|".

As you can see in my code I am following the format with requests containing something like this >> 3.222,54.333 | 2.444, 66.4332 | ...

This should be working from what I can tell but clearly something is wrong.

here is a segment of the code, the program breaks at the error point within this block.

```
finalStringConvertedCoordinates = processedQueryPoints.joined(separator: "|")
        let apiKey = "REDACTED"
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?key=\(apiKey)&locations=\(finalStringConvertedCoordinates)") else {
                    print("Error: cannot create URL")
                    return
```

Comment: try to print the error message. Also, try to print finalStringConvertedCoordinates to be sure that the string is valid

Comment: can you show an example of "processedQueryPoints"

Comment: Hi @workingdog the processedQueryPoints are like so 3.222,54.333 | 2.444, 66.4332 |...  they follow that format

Comment: so there is no need for joined(separator: "|")

Comment: @workingdog. Apologies, no, I described this badly. The layout of processedQueryPoints is like so.  [33.2343, 55.3383, 33.2323, 44.6545] It is an array of strings which is being appended to. Each pair of coordinates is at a different address within the Array

Comment: that look like an array of numbers. Which is it an array of string or numbers. And what does " Each pair of coordinates is at a different address within the Array" mean? Can you give a real example?

Comment: They are strings at this point, they where converted before being inserted into processedQueryPoints. in regard to Different addresses its like so [lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3]  each of these represents coordinates. So, the array would look like this in terms of elements [0,1,2].     lat1,lon1 at address 0, lat2,lon2 at address 1. and so on.   Just to clarify the request runs just fine until there are more than one pair of coordinates given.

Comment: Can you give a real practical example of say 2 locations?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote you. Thank you for your help. Anyone in future experiencing this issue this is the answer to look at. Thank you very much working dog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, once you figure out what's in processedQueryPoints:

```
        let locations = ["3.222,54.333", "2.444,66.4332"]
        let locs = locations.joined(separator: "%7C")  // <-- the important bit
        print("\n---> locs: \(locs)")
        let apiKey = "REDACTED"
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=\(locs)&key=\(apiKey)")
        print("---> url: \(url) \n")
```

EDIT: starting with an array of strings as described:

```
        let rawData = ["3.222","54.333", "2.444","66.4332"]
        print("\n---> rawData: \(rawData)")
        
        let pairs = stride(from: 0, to: rawData.endIndex, by: 2).map {(rawData[$0], rawData[$0.advanced(by: 1)])}
        print("\n---> pairs: \(pairs)")
        
        let locs = pairs.map{ $0 + "," + $1 }.joined(separator: "%7C")
        print("\n---> locs: \(locs)")
        
        let apiKey = "REDACTED"
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=\(locs)&key=\(apiKey)")
        print("---> url: \(url) \n")
```